# How to display PDF in webview from assets folder android

Tags: android, pdf, webview

I surfed a lot for  this solution but everywhere I got same solution i.e. either use Intent and pass it to default/installed PdfReader applications, Other one is to use gview from googleDocs to load Pdfs online.

But my question is how can view my pdf offline in webview i.e. if user click on list of pdf in my application don't go to other application or google/gview  .

I tried passing assets folder path but not working getting message in webview that "webpage is temporarily down or move permanently."

I also tried this link.. which describes to use pdfViewver.jar but that lib. has it's own issues that needs to be fixed.

any help will highly appreciated

Comment: what was your assets folder path?

Comment: webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/doc/programme_green_design"); I pass this way to webview also tried by adding extention .pdf but getting msg that it's temporarily down or permanatly moved"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But my question is how can view my pdf offline in webview

You can't. `WebView` cannot display PDFs on its own.

Comment: thanks for reply .. 
so, is there any lib. which helps to do this, because I don't want to send my app user to default applications.

Comment: @AndriodNewbie: The best answer is to get rid of the PDF and switch to HTML, so you can use `WebView` directly. There are open source PDF viewing libraries, and reportedly they are all fairly lousy. There are commercial viewing libraries, and reportedly they are all expensive. Personally, I have used neither type of library -- if I am going to show a PDF, I will use a PDF viewing app.